# UBUNTU: ¿Dónde instalo los programas que que descargo en tar.gz?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ide

Soy nuevo en Ubuntu y como ejemplo podría poner a Netbeans o Intellj Idea, estos programas tienen un setup ".sh" para poder instalarlos pero se instalan en la carpeta personal del sistema y no se si es correcto o debo ponerlos en otra.

Comment: Descomprime el archivo donde tú quieras... Para iniciar el programa, sólo ejecuta el archivo correspondiente. En el caso de NetBeans, te recomiendo el zip multiplataforma.

Comment: Netbeans deja elegir el path donde se quiera instalar, por defecto viene el directorio /opt/netbeans-xx, en ese directorio puedes instalarlo tranquilamente.

Comment: Claro, entonces los programas van en /opt ?

Comment: De acuerdo a la documentacion oficial si, en resumen la documentacion dice: Este directorio es reservado para todo el software y paquetes adicionales que no son parte de la instalacion por default. En el siguiente link puedes revisarlo http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias Juan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación oficial se puede instalar tranquilamente los programas en /opt, la documentación dice:

> Este directorio es reservado para todo el software y paquetes
>   adicionales que no son parte de la instalación por default.

En el siguiente link puedes revisarlo: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html

Answer (score 0):

No hay una norma definida para ello, pero por lo general se suele descomprimir en **/opt**. Personalmente, le cambio dueño a este directorio por mi usuario en lugar de root: `sudo chown -R tusuario:tuusuario /opt`.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentan,realmente puedes instalarlos donde quieras. Quizás lo recomendable sería en /opt porque esta destinado para ello.

¿Problema? si tienes particionado el disco , una particion para / y otra para /home, si instalas cosas pesadas en /opt y no tienes mucho espacio en esa partición, se va a llenar pronto. Aparte que si formateas / pierdes los programas.

Por eso yo el Netbeans, Eclipse, Android Studio, y cosas asi tochas, las pongo en mi /home. Van a funcionar igualmente lo pongas donde lo pongas.

Un saludo